# Formats supported by BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(...)

Tags: android, android-image

Is it documented (or reasonable to assume) that [BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(...)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeByteArray%28byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29) can be expected to recognize any of the image formats listed [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html#core)?

Comment: Yes (reasonable to assume). But WebP is only for Android 4.0+. PNG, JPG, GIF (... BMP ??) are common formats for Android. If the can be used as backgrounds, it's reasonable to assune that BitmapFactory will handle them.

Comment: One would have thought that the BitmapFactory documentation would contain this information.  That lack of documentation led me to find this question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, it's reasonable to assume (a bit more so if you take a peek at the source code of AOSP). The JNI native methods for `BitmapFactory` are in `BitmapFactory.cpp`.

https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/jni/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.cpp

Since both `BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray()` and the `BitmapDrawable(InputStream)` constructor end up calling `doDecode()`, and since this constructor is used when loading resources from the APK, it would be reasonable to assume that the capabilities are the same.